# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null

Tags: javascript

I used this line in js file

```
document.getElementById("orderbutton").disabled = true;
```

I used a button with id "orderbutton" on page example.php
and in other page example1.php, I am not using the button with "orderbutton"

When opening the page example1.php in the console I have this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null

any help, please
example1.php file

Comment: You need to show relevant `example1.php` part.

Comment: The error simply means that `document.getElementById()` is returning `null`, so you cannot access any properties of something that does not exist.

Comment: [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: make sure you have the id="orderbutton" in your html

Comment: yeah i have in example.php but i am not used in example1.php

Answer (score 2):

probably 'orderbutton' doesn't exist in html code.
Check that the button exists or maybe case sensitive error.